# How to I change the value of a boolean from true to false, and permanently keep it true after a button is pressed?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In this code, I click on button for level 1, and I play out level 1. Once I return back to the map, level 2 should be unlocked because I set the boolean to true when I pressed button 1.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainButtons : MonoBehaviour

{
  private bool level2Ready;
    private bool level3Ready;
    private bool level4Ready;
    private bool level5Ready;


 void Start()
    {
       level2Ready = false;
       level3Ready = false;
       level4Ready = false;
       level5Ready = false;
    }

public void Level1Map() { //button 1 in the map is pressed
      level2Ready = !level2Ready; // unlocks level 2 button
      SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }


public void Level2Map() { // level 2 button is pressed
      if (level2Ready == true) {
      SceneManager.LoadScene(4); //loads level 2 game scene
      level3Ready = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scene is loaded when you press the button. If this script is also in the Level2, then `Start()` is called once again when loading Level2 with `SceneManager.LoadScene(0)`. This sets everything back to `false`. You need to persist the parent object of this script `MainButtons` (Assuming something like a scene or state manager).

You can do it with a call to [`Object.DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the state in your component (which may be reloaded, and reset) `MainButtons`, you can keep them in a static class:

For example something like...

```
public static class LevelReadyManager
{
    public static bool level2Ready;
    public static bool level3Ready;
    public static bool level4Ready;
    public static bool level5Ready;
}
```

and then your component would use them like this:

```
public class MainButtons : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void Level1Map() { 
        LevelReadyManager.level2Ready = !LevelReadyManager.level2Ready; 
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }


   public void Level2Map() { 
       if (LevelReadyManager.level2Ready == true) {
           SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
            LevelReadyManager.level3Ready = true;
      }
   }

}
```

Because we make them static, they not be instansiated and not dependent on any GameObject, thus persist even though you change scenes and unload/create new objects etc.